# Storing list of generic class of derived objects

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

For example, how do I store a list of DataContainers that all use types that derive from the same base class.

```
public class Animal {}
public class Cat : Animal {}
public class Dog : Animal {}
public class DataContainer <TData> where TData : Animal {
    TData innerObject = new TData ();
    public TData GetData () {
        return innerObject;
    }
}

public class DataManager {
    static void Main () {
        DataContainer<Cat> CatData = new DataContainer<Cat> ();
        DataContainer<Dog> DogData = new DataContainer<Dog> ();
        var AnimalData = new List<DataContainer<Animal>> ();
        AnimalData.Add (CatData);
        AnimalData.Add (DogData);
        for (int i = 0; i < AnimalData.Count; i++) {
            Animal animal = AnimalData[i].GetData ();
        }
    }
}
```

If it's not possible with a generic class, could it be possible with Arrays?

Edit: Getting this error: `ArrayTypeMismatchException: Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type.` This causes an ArrayTypeMismatchException:

```
public interface IDataContainer <out TData> where TData : Animal {

}
public class DataContainer <TData> : IDataContainer<TData> where TData : Animal {

}

public class Tester () {
    static void Main () {
        var AnimalData = new List<DataContainer<Animal>> ();
        var CatData = new DataContainer<Cat> ();
        AnimalData.Add (CatData as IDataContainer<Animal>); //Error
    }
}
```

Run in Unity 5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you need your generic class to have a [**covariant**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) type parameter.

You can only do this on interfaces, so create one:

```
public interface IDataContainer <out TData> where TData : Animal 
{
    TData GetData ();
}
```

Note the use of `out` to mark `TData` as covariant. Now have your `DataContainer` class implement the interface, and when you hold onto a reference in the client code, make sure its an `IDataContainer`. Now it should let you store it as you expected.

Do note that covariant interfaces have special requirements, namely that the generic type parameter can not be used as the argument type for any of the methods (see the MSDN link for more).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: The casting works but is there any way to add a covariant object to a collection?

Comment: @user196399 Not sure what you mean (and there is no casting in my example) Perhaps provide a code example, or ask a new question and send me a link?

Comment: Like in the question's code, I want to add covariant objects to a list or some sort of collection so I can iterate over all DataContainers. `AnimalData.Add (CatData as IDataContainer<Animal>);`

Comment: DId you make the List be a `List<IDataContainer<Animal>` first? That should have worked

Comment: Yes, but it throws an ArrayMismatchError. Could it have something to do with not having the generic type parameter not being able to be used as the argument type?

Comment: @user196399 It should just work, and I'm not familiar with that exception. If it compiles at all, it should just work. Perhaps you could update your question with the code (or ask a new one about this error).

Comment: I've reached my question limit :(. I'll edit it into the OP.

Comment: @user196399 Try making your list be `List<IDataContainer<Animal>>`

Comment: @user196399 You could also try `IList` instead of `List`

Comment: @user196399 I would look up the exception and see if you can figure out what is happening

Comment: I'll give it a shot. At the moment, it's a non-issue but hopefully I can find a solution eventually.