# ArrayTypeMismatchException: Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Unity** : 2017.3.0f3 (same on 5.x)

I got the exact same problem as this question :
[Storing list of generic class of derived objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181041/storing-list-of-generic-class-of-derived-objects)

```
public interface Animal { void bar(); }
public interface IContainer <out T> where T : Animal { void foo();}
public class Cat : Animal{ void bar(){} }
public class CatContainer : IContainer<Cat>{ void foo(){} }

/* ... */

public void test () {
        List<IContainer<Animal> list= new List<IContainer<Animal>> ();
        list.Add (new CatContainer()); //Error
}
```

When I push the `new CatContainer()` into the list I got this exception :

```
ArrayTypeMismatchException: Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type.
(wrapper stelemref) object:stelemref (object,intptr,object)
```

**NOTE: This code works outside Unity.**

Do you have this problem too ? Is there a workaround ?

Comment: It seems that it's an Unity issue since 2013... https://forum.unity.com/threads/generic-variance-issues.337830/ and https://answers.unity.com/questions/456135/c-covariancearrays-raises-arraytypemismatchexcepti.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and found out that it was problem with mono.
Your code throws an exception on the `Mono .NET 3.5 equivalent`. However,it works fine on `Mono .NET 4.6 equivalent`.
Goto `Player Settings/Other Settings/Configuration/Scripting Runtime Version` and set this field to `Experimental (.NET 4.6 Equivalent)`.
[image]

Comment: have you had other issues needing to use the experimental 4.6?